# Subfolders using htaccess

Tags: php, url, .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdirectory

I want to have use something like this:

> http://localhost/test/dummy

instead of this:

> http://localhost/test/profile.php?id=dummy

I know that it can be done with URL Rewrite in .htaccess, but I don't know how exactly it works, so I can't make it work!

Can I anyone please help me??

Comment: You can find plenty of tutorials on the Internet. You can also use a framework. Frameworks always have a built-in URL Rewriting module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /test
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! -d
RewriteRule (.*) profile.php?id=$1
```

also read this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html