# Subfolders Url rewriting using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i am working within sub folder of my website and i want to rewrite my urls.

i have never done this before nor have any knowledge of rewriting rules.

I have a file which named show.php which takes parameter id which is any no and then it echo that no on to the screen.

Now this file is in folder name polo.

```
    www.xyz.com/polo/show.php
```

i want to rewrite

```
    www.xyz.com/polo/show.php?id=10
```

to

```
    www.xyz.com/polo/id/10
```

I tried this answer but still its not working.

[Subfolders using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687619/subfolders-using-htaccess)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(polo)/(id)/([0-9]+)/?$ /$1/show.php?$2=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: its not working here is live url iam testing on  http://www.seooutlook.com/polo/show?id=565656

Comment: `http://www.seooutlook.com/polo/id/565658` is generating 500 error. Can you check your error.log and tell me what is the error there.

Comment: when iam using http://www.seooutlook.com/polo/id/10/ It returns 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Can you check your error.log and tell me what is the error there.

Comment: Last error was at [Thu Aug 22 09:18:36 2013] [error] [client 106.67.24.104] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /home/seooutlo/public_html/polo/

Comment: Ok comment out Options line above and then retry.

Comment: ur solution is working now .. it seems like this error is occuring because of my other rewrite rule in .htaccess file.